# how the iterator of ConcurrentHashMap works on the clone of original object?

Tags: java, concurrenthashmap

We know that ConcurrentHashMap doesn't implement Cloneable interface but we also know that it's iterator works on clone of the original object. If it doesn't implement the particular interface, how this behavior is in place?